# What does "Well." mean when it's used as a drop-off sentence, like "Well then."?

Tags: expressions, phrase-meaning

Does it mean "well too bad/sorry/couldn't do that unfortunately"? I have a sense of what it means but not very precisely.

Comment: It could mean anything. Without context, it is impossible to say.

Comment: It's an exclamation.  And it's meaning is fairly context-dependent.

Comment: Why not report what you found in a dictionary?

Comment: @GEdgar I should have clarified that I'm referring to an informal literary usage that isn't going to be found in a dictionary. To be precise, I meant "Well." not as in "I'm well", but humorously, when all of the possible ways the sentence could end but not any particular one are implied, as a comment. Kind of like "Well then.", which I know the meaning of.

Answer (score 1):

When it's a single-word sentence, it can mean lots of things.

It can answer a question:

- Me: "How are you today?" You: *"Well."

But usually it's just a meaningless filler. For instance, you can use it to:

- stall when you're trying to decide how to phrase something: You: "Only a complete idiot would vote for him." Me: "Well. I thought he was the lesser of two evils."
- get people's attention: "Well. Is everyone ready to settle down?"
- end a discussion: "Well. Then let's all get back to work, shall we?